# Help with 1080p on tv via laptop

Tags: 10.04, graphics

**UPDATE 1:**

According to [this](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-022544.htm) and [this](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/855gm-gme-chipset-graphics-memory-controller-hub-datasheet.html), 1920x1080 should be possible:

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

According to `lshw` my laptop has:

```
VGA compatible controller
product: 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device
vendor: Intel Corporation
version: 02
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
```

The laptop has a vga port allowing me to connect to my tv which also has a vga port, but I am only getting 1024x768 on the tv.  How can I get 1920x1080 on the tv?

I have a 1080p tv.

Comment: Have you tried to change the resolution with the Displays settings dialogue?

Comment: Yes, but the only options I get are 800x600 and 1024x768.

Comment: Please see update to original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same chipset on my laptop with a VGA output.

In lucid the graphics drivers for this chipset were awful - it barely managed 1024x768 at a decent FPS rate.  When I connected it to my HD tv it managed 1280x768 (i.e. widescreen) but the FPS rate was shockingly low.

Things somewhat improved with the Natty kernel (available in the software repositories) - from the [community wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Lucidi8xxFreezes):

> A few months Canonical has backported kernel version 2.6.38 from Ubuntu 11.04 and version 3.0 from Ubuntu 11.10. Both versions include
>   the bugfix for the 855GM-problem. It is strongly advised to use one of
>   these kernel versions because the 855GM-PPA was deactivated some time
>   ago.

Again I managed 1280x768 with a slightly better refresh rate.

A word of warning - take an drive-image backup if you intend to use the newer kernel.  It took me a few attempts to get things working - for me I used Stefan Glasenhard PPA (as described in the link) and the Natty kernel to get a stable configuration.

The figures you have been quoted by Intel themselves are theoretical - you will not be able to achieve this on linux with the state of the graphics drivers.  Intel themselves are no longer supporting i8xx - the support for i8xx under 12.04 is not known - but given that only VESA support was available in Natty and Oneiric and dont hold out much hope.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt that particular GPU can output video at 1920x1080, after all, it's about 9 years old.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets

I'd be surprised if it could drive even one display with a resolution higher then 1024x768 without freezing, let alone an HD TV. If you are interested in what it can do, run `xrandr` in a terminal window.

Comment: I have an Intel i8xx video card and I use the same driver and I can't output video to more than 1024x768. Don't think it is possible.

Comment: Please see update to original question.